# Can't type anything when using getchar() in this program

Tags: c, gcc, getchar

I am studying "The C Programming Language, 2nd Ed." by Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie. I was on Exercise 1-19 of the book. The question asks to define a function reverse(s) which reverses a character string a. And we have to write a program which reverses it's input one at a time.

```
//This program is working on online compiler but not here
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse(char s[]);

int main(void) {
    int h = 0; // sort of automatic variable just to
               // keep storing characters in current line
    char s[200];
    char c;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        s[i] = '\0';
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c != '\n') {
            s[h++] = c;
        } else {
            s[h++] = c;
            h = 0;
            reverse(s);
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                s[i] = '\0';
        }
    }
}

void reverse(char s[]) {
    int i = 200;
    while(i >= 0)
        if(s[i--] != '\0')
            putchar(s[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

So when I run this code with gcc on my system, I don't get any errors while compiling, but I can't type any input for some reason. However, the program runs correctly when I use an online C compiler.

Comment: `char s[200];  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) s[i] = '\0';` Do you notice?

Comment: ...and `int i = 200;` is off-by-one in the function too.

Comment: `getchar` returns an `int`, and the values it returns may be outside the range of `char`

Comment: @kirjosieppo Oh, I am so stupid. But I am still curious, why was this working fine on the online compiler?

Comment: Because undefined behavior sometimes exhibits behavior that is "fine".

Answer (score 0):

```
void reverse(char s[]) {
    int i = 200;
    while(i >= 0)
        if(s[i--] != '\0')
            putchar(s[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

if you postdecrement your string index, you are first using value at 200 position, which is invalid (it's one position out of the array) so you are doing bad.  To do it properly, you need to predecrement it, as in:

```
void reverse(char s[]) {
    int i = 200;
    while(i >= 0)
        if(s[--i] != '\0')
            putchar(s[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

but there's still an error... as you pass a null terminated string, you cannot be sure of what there is in the array after the null.... (can be another null?) so you have to search for the null from the beginning of the string (and this is good, because the most of the time you will feed the routine short strings, and now you don't depend on the array size, which you assumed by a constant 200.  One good way to do it is with the `strlen()` function, as in:

```
void reverse(char s[]) {
    int i = strlen(s);
    while(i >= 0) /* ??? see below */
        if(s[--i] != '\0')
            putchar(s[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

and then, the test you do is not necessary at all (you already found the leftmost null):

```
void reverse(char s[]) {
    int i = strlen(s);
    while(i >= 0) /* still more below VVV */
            putchar(s[--i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

... and there's still a little mistake... you have to stop when `i <= 0` and not when `i < 0` as you are predecrementing now:

```
void reverse(char s[]) {
    int i = strlen(s);
    while(i > 0) /* here!! */
            putchar(s[--i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```